# Minimize number of operations to compute thousands of expressions over hundreds of variables

Tags: algorithms

I have an expensive operation; I'll use the symbol `+` and the word "concatenation" to represent it. This operation is:

- Binary: `A + B`
- Associative: `(A + B) + C == A + (B + C)`
- Non-commutative: `A + B != B + A`
- Idempotent: `A + A == A`

These properties mean, for instance, `(A + B) + (B + C) == A + B + C` and `(A + B) + (C + B) == A + B + C + B`.

I have thousands of expressions, each with about 10 variables that come from a pool of a few hundred variables, and I want to be able to find as optimal a way as I can to calculate the results of all those expressions; meaning, with the fewest number of executions of the operation. What are some algorithms and keywords I should research?

## Further Details

I have multiple expressions like this:

- `A + B + C`
- `B + C + D`

In that example, there are naively 4 operations required to compute the results of those expressions, but I can do it with 3 if I cache the result of `B + C`:

- `BC = B + C`
- `A + BC`
- `BC + D`

If I also include the following expressions:

- `C + D + E`
- `C + D + F`

the naive number of operations is 8, but I can do the computation with 6 like so:

- `BC = B + C`
- `A + BC`
- `BC + D`
- `CD = C + D`
- `CD + E`
- `CD + F`

or like so:

- `A + B + C`
- `CD = C + D`
- `B + CD`
- `CD + E`
- `CD + F`

One more example:

- `A + B + C + D + E`
- `A + B + C + D + F`
- `A + B + C + D + G`
- `A + B + C + D + H`
- `A + B + X`
- `B + C + Y`
- `C + D + Z`

which is naively 22 operations, but I can get it down to 11:

- `AB = A + B`
- `CD = C + D`
- `ABCD = AB + CD`
- `ABCD + E`
- `ABCD + F`
- `ABCD + G`
- `ABCD + H`
- `AB + X`
- `B + C + Y`
- `CD + Z`

Comment: [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) is interesting, as well as some of the nearby articles.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorial_addition_chain

Comment: @D.W. You're the second person to mention addition chains – and specifically vectorial addition chains – in relation to this. I've taken a look and I can at least see the resemblance to addition chains, but I haven't made the mental connection with vectorial addition chains yet. Also the article mentions abelian (commutative) groups, whereas my operation is non-commutative.

Comment: This CSE function in SymPy looks like it might be helpful: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#cse

Comment: Oh!  I missed that your operation is non-commutative.  If you had a single target (instead of thousands of targets), and you were working with a commutative addition, your problem would be exactly the vectorial addition chain problem.  I don't know whether the techniques for that could be potentially be applied to multi-target addition chains.  The variable $A$ corresponds to the vector $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$, the variable $B$ corresponds to the vector $(0,1,0,\dots,0)$, and so on.  Sorry for missing the non-commutative part.

Comment: Can we prove that exploiting idempotence is always optimal? So if there is a substring … ABCABC .., is it always optimal to replace this with … ABC …?

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, `ABCABC == ABC`.